# Python del operator not working in my for loop

Tags: python

I'm very new to python and have read what I could find on for loops and the del operator, but I still don't understand why my solution to the problem below isn't working:

**PROBLEM**

Given a string, return a new string made of every other char starting with the first, so `"Hello"` yields `"Hlo"`.

```
string_bits('Hello') → 'Hlo'
string_bits('Hi') → 'H'
string_bits('Heeololeo') → 'Hello'
```

**SOLUTION**

```
def string_bits(str):
    for i in range(len(str)):
      if i % 2 != 0:
        del[i]
    return str
```

This just returns a replica of the original string and doesn't delete anything - why aren't the odd numbers in the range being deleted?

Comment: Note: even if that were possible, `del[i]` wouldn't be the correct syntax; you're deleting the name `i`, not a piece of the sequence `str`. Also, don't name a variable `str`.

Answer (score 4):

Strings are immutable, meaning you can't just delete arbitrary characters.

To solve your problem I would use slice notation

```
x = 'Heeololeo'

y = x[::2]

print(y) # Hello
```

You can find the details [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't change something that you are iterating over. You should extract the data you need and save it to a new variable and return that.

Answer (score 1):

First, strings are immutable. Second, you're not supposed to modify an iterable while iterating over it.

Make a copy of it, or use a filter:

```
new_string = ''.join(c for i, c in enumerate(old_string) if i%2 != 0)
```

Simplified version:

```
result = []
for i, c in enumerate(old_string):
    if i%2 != 0:
        result.append(c)
new_string = ''.join(result)
```

An easier, cooler way is to make a slice of it, with the [extended slice notation](http://docs.python.org/2.3/whatsnew/section-slices.html):

```
new_string = old_string[::2]
```

Also, avoid using names like `str`, you'll shadow the useful built-in function.

Answer (score 1):

strings in Python are `immutable`, meaning that once they are created, they can't be changed. All functions that seem to "change" strings actually return a new version of the string.

Regardless, a good rule of thumb is to not change things you're iterating over. You could use a list comprehension to create a new string with only the character that you want.